# Query EC2 tags from within instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Amazon recently added the wonderful feature of tagging EC2 instances with key-value pairs to make management of large numbers of VMs a bit easier.

Is there some way to query these tags in the same way as some of the other user-set data? For example:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
us-east-1d
```

Is there some similar way to query the tags?

Comment: The solution (in 2023) is to call the magic url `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance`. This will return a string list of tags (e.g. `Environment Name` ), and then you just append them to the url eg `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance/Environment` which returns the text value of the tag.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use a combination of the [AWS metadata tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html) (to retrieve your instance ID) and the [new Tag API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?Using_Tags.html) to retrieve the tags for the current instance.

Comment: OK, I followed that link, and it looks like it's the API documentation. Is there no tool that I can use, or do I need to read the API documentation and write my own tool?

Comment: Is the ec2-describe-tags command easily available? Supposedly it's in the ec2-api-tools package, but I got nothing but 404's when I tried to install it.

Comment: give a example, get tag role 's value:  

aws ec2 describe-tags --filters Name=resource-id,Values=`ec2metadata --instance-id` --out=json|jq '.Tags[]| select(.Key == "role")|.Value'

Comment: This is a pointer to an answer but not an answer in-and-of itself

Comment: The `ec2metadata` tool is deprecated. Now you query the 'magic' URL at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ - hit it with cURL and it gives you magic endpoints you can use to get various bits of data. In this case `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id` gets your your instance ID

Comment: "Suggested edit queue is full" haha - but the correct answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51514857 and non answers are not in the spirit of SO

Comment: I made it into a community wiki. I haven't touched this stuff in about a decade so I'll leave it to others to maintain the answer.

Answer (score 84):

The following bash script returns the Name of your current ec2 instance (the value of the "Name" tag). Modify TAG_NAME to your specific case.

```
TAG_NAME="Name"
INSTANCE_ID="`wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id`"
REGION="`wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed -e 's:\([0-9][0-9]*\)[a-z]*\$:\\1:'`"
TAG_VALUE="`aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID" "Name=key,Values=$TAG_NAME" --region $REGION --output=text | cut -f5`"
```

To install the aws cli

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip -y
sudo pip install awscli
```

In case you use IAM instead of explicit credentials, use these IAM permissions:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {    
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [ "ec2:DescribeTags"],
      "Resource": ["*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I was getting "You are not authorized to perform this operation" with `aws ec2 describe-tags`. I needed to add this IAM to the inline policies of my IAM role. Thanks!

Comment: A very slight optimization COULD be to replace the `| cut -f5` with `--query="Tags[0].Value"`.

Comment: I would just like to say that this is the best answer to a question I've seen in a while. Concise, complete, task oriented. It includes unasked for but entirely reasonable additional info. I'd like to suggest that everyone everywhere write documentation in this style.

Comment: You need AWS credentials installed. Which is not covered here.

Answer (score 47):

Once you've got `ec2-metadata` and `ec2-describe-tags` installed (as mentioned in [Ranieri's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883315/query-ec2-tags-from-within-instance/3890289#3890289)), here's an example shell command to get the "name" of the current instance, assuming you have a "Name=Foo" tag on it.

Assumes EC2_PRIVATE_KEY and EC2_CERT environment variables are set.

```
ec2-describe-tags \
  --filter "resource-type=instance" \
  --filter "resource-id=$(ec2-metadata -i | cut -d ' ' -f2)" \
  --filter "key=Name" | cut -f5
```

This returns `Foo`.

Comment: It would have been nice if my processes could get the tags for the current instance without having to have the EC2_PRIVATE_KEY on the instance as well. :-(

Comment: @william-payne Yeah, that is really lame.  Perhaps using Amazon's IAM you could at least use a user with very limited access to anything.  FWIW, I don't use this approach any more and just use external scripts to setup the box.

Comment: @WilliamPayne You can set up an IAM Role with the "Amazon EC2 Read Only Access" policy and create the instance having that role.  It is also possible to create a custom policy having only the "DescribeTags" privilege if you want to be more granular.

Comment: @WilliamPayne I liked roverwolf's suggestion.  It worked great.  I actually answered another question with the details if you want to see it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950586/how-to-pass-environment-variables-when-programmatically-starting-a-new-amazon-ec

Comment: Note that `ec2-describe-tags` defaults to `us-east-2`. Please pass the `--region` flag to use a different region.

Comment: Can be done with standard AWS cli too:
`aws ec2 describe-tags --region eu-west-1 --filters "Name=resource-type,Values=instance" "Name=resource-id,Values=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id | cut -d ' ' -f2)" "Name=key,Values=Name" --output text | cut -f5`

Answer (score 20):

You can add this script to your **cloud-init** user data to download EC2 tags to a local file:

```
#!/bin/sh
INSTANCE_ID=`wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
REGION=`wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/.$//'`
aws ec2 describe-tags --region $REGION --filter "Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID" --output=text | sed -r 's/TAGS\t(.*)\t.*\t.*\t(.*)/\1="\2"/' > /etc/ec2-tags
```

You need the AWS CLI tools installed on your system: you can either install them with a `packages` section in a cloud-config file before the script, use an AMI that already includes them, or add an `apt` or `yum` command at the beginning of the script.

In order to access EC2 tags you need a policy like this one in your instance's IAM role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1409309287000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeTags"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The instance's EC2 tags will available in `/etc/ec2-tags` in this format:

```
FOO="Bar"
Name="EC2 tags with cloud-init"
```

You can include the file as-is in a shell script using `. /etc/ec2-tags`, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/ec2-tags
echo $Name
```

The tags are downloaded during instance initialization, so they will not reflect subsequent changes.

---

The script and IAM policy are based on itaifrenkel's answer.

Comment: a+ prefer this method

Comment: too bad this breaks for tags created by autoscaling groups: `aws:autoscaling:groupName`

Comment: Then try this:
`aws ec2 describe-tags --region $REGION --filter "Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID" --output=text | sed -r 's/TAGS\t(.*)\t.*\t.*\t(.*)/EC2_TAG_\1="\2"/' |sed -r 's/aws:autoscaling:/aws_autoscaling_/' > /etc/ec2-tags`

Comment: You no longer need to chop up the availability zone; you can directly retrieve http:/169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region

Answer (score 11):

If you are not in the default availability zone the results from overthink would return empty.

```
ec2-describe-tags \
   --region \
     $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone  | sed -e "s/.$//") \
   --filter \
     resource-id=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
```

If you want to add a filter to get a specific tag (elasticbeanstalk:environment-name in my case) then you can do this.

```
ec2-describe-tags \
   --region \
     $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone  | sed -e "s/.$//") \
   --filter \
     resource-id=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) \
   --filter \
     key=elasticbeanstalk:environment-name | cut -f5
```

And to get only the value for the tag that I filtered on, we pipe to cut and get the fifth field.

```
ec2-describe-tags \
  --region \
    $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone  | sed -e "s/.$//") \
  --filter \
    resource-id=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) \
  --filter \
    key=elasticbeanstalk:environment-name | cut -f5
```

Comment: great work , thank you , having a different dns instance-data is not working for me , for the last one if you need the Name tag replace `elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` with `Name`

Answer (score 8):

You can alternatively use the `describe-instances` cli call rather than `describe-tags`:

This example shows how to get the value of tag 'my-tag-name' for the instance:

```bash
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 10"`
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --instance-id $(curl -s -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) \
  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].Tags[?Key=='my-tag-name'].Value" \
  --region ap-southeast-2 --output text
```

Change the region to suit your local circumstances, or retrieve it using one of the other answers to this question. This may be useful where your instance has the describe-instances privilege on itself, but not describe-tags in the instance profile policy

Answer (score 8):

Starting January 2022, this should be also available directly via ec2 metadata  api (if enabled).

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance
```

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/01/instance-tags-amazon-ec2-instance-metadata-service/

Answer (score 7):

I have pieced together the following that is hopefully simpler and cleaner than some of the existing answers and uses only the AWS CLI and no additional tools.

This code example shows how to get the value of tag 'myTag' for the current EC2 instance:

Using [describe-tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-tags.html):

```bash
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
instance_id=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
aws ec2 describe-tags \
  --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$instance_id" 'Name=key,Values=myTag' \
  --query 'Tags[].Value' --output text
```

Or, alternatively, using [describe-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html):

```bash
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $instance_id \
  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[?Key==`myTag`].Value' --output text
```

Answer (score 5):

For Python:

```
from boto import utils, ec2
from os import environ

# import keys from os.env or use default (not secure)
aws_access_key_id = environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', failobj='XXXXXXXXXXX')
aws_secret_access_key = environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', failobj='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

#load metadata , if  = {} we are on localhost
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html
instance_metadata = utils.get_instance_metadata(timeout=0.5, num_retries=1)
region = instance_metadata['placement']['availability-zone'][:-1]
instance_id = instance_metadata['instance-id']

conn = ec2.connect_to_region(region, aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
# get tag status for our  instance_id using filters
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeTags.html
tags = conn.get_all_tags(filters={'resource-id': instance_id, 'key': 'status'})
if tags:
    instance_status = tags[0].value
else:
    instance_status = None
    logging.error('no status tag for '+region+' '+instance_id)
```

Comment: Legit. Readers note for basic local info you don't even need credentials, just the `instance_metadata = utils.get_instance_metadata(timeout=0.5, num_retries=1)`

Comment: Also, this plays nicely with IAM roles - if you set an instance role, boto will automatically detect the ID and key.

Answer (score 4):

A variation on some of the answers above but this is how I got the value of a specific tag from the user-data script on an instance

```
REGION=$(curl http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/.$//')

INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id)

TAG_VALUE=$(aws ec2 describe-tags --region $REGION --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID" "Name=key,Values='<TAG_NAME_HERE>'" | jq -r '.Tags[].Value')
```

Answer (score 3):

Jq + ec2metadata makes it a little nicer. I'm using cf and have access to the region. Otherwise you can grab it in bash.

```sh
aws ec2 describe-tags --region $REGION \
--filters "Name=resource-id,Values=`ec2metadata --instance-id`" | jq --raw-output \
'.Tags[] | select(.Key=="TAG_NAME") | .Value'
```

No jq.

```sh
aws ec2 describe-tags --region us-west-2 \
--filters "Name=resource-id,Values=`ec2-metadata --instance-id | cut -d " " -f 2`" \
--query 'Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value' \
--output text
```

Comment: This should have more upvotes in 2019 and beyond as many of the other answers no longer work.  CLI version 2 perhaps?   In any case this worked for me out of the box but you do need to have the describe-tags permission granted to the instance's IAM role.  Oh and get the right region with ec2-metadata -z | sed 's/.$//' as per other answers.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to get Instance tags from within the instance via metadata.

First, allow access to tags in instance metadata as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#allow-access-to-tags-in-IMDS)

Then, run this command for IMDSv1, [Refer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html#instance-metadata-ex-7)

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance/Name
```

or this command for IMDSv2

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"` \
&& curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the AWS 'user data' and 'meta data' APIs its possible to write a script which wraps puppet to start a puppet run with a custom cert name.

First start an aws instance with custom user data: 'role:webserver'

```
#!/bin/bash

# Find the name from the user data passed in on instance creation
USER=$(curl -s "http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data")
IFS=':' read -ra UDATA <<< "$USER"

# Find the instance ID from the meta data api
ID=$(curl -s "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")
CERTNAME=${UDATA[1]}.$ID.aws

echo "Running Puppet for certname: " $CERTNAME
puppet agent -t --certname=$CERTNAME
```

This calls puppet with a certname like 'webserver.i-hfg453.aws' you can then create a node manifest called 'webserver' and puppets 'fuzzy node matching' will mean it is used to provision all webservers.

This example assumes you build on a base image with puppet installed etc.

Benefits:

1) You don't have to pass round your credentials

2) You can be as granular as you like with the role configs.

Answer (score 2):

The solution (in 2023) is to call the magic url `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance`. They need to be enabled in the Advanced Settings during Instance creation.

[image]

This will return a string list of tags (e.g. `Environment\nName` ), and then you just append them to the url eg `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance/Environment` which returns the text value of the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Download and run a standalone executable to do that.

Sometimes one cannot install awscli that depends on python. docker might be out of the picture too.

Here is my implementation in golang:
https://github.com/hmalphettes/go-ec2-describe-tags

Answer (score 1):

The Metadata tool seems to no longer be available, but that was an unnecessary dependency anyway.

Follow the AWS documentation to have the instance's profile grant it the "ec2:DescribeTags" action in a policy, restricting the target resources as much as you wish.  (If you need a profile for another reason then you'll need to merge policies into a new profile-linked role).

Then:

```
aws --region $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone  | sed -e 's/.$//') ec2 describe-tags --filters Name=resource-type,Values=instance Name=resource-id,Values=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) Name=key,Values=Name |
perl -nwe 'print "$1\n" if /"Value": "([^"]+)/;'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there are lots of good answers here but none quite worked for me exactly out of the box, I think the CLI has been updated since some of them and I do like using the CLI.  The following single command works out of the box for me in 2021 (as long as the instance's IAM role is allowed to describe-tags).

```
aws ec2 describe-tags \
--region "$(ec2-metadata -z | cut -d' ' -f2 | sed 's/.$//')" \
--filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$(ec2-metadata --instance-id | cut -d " " -f 2)" \
--query 'Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value' \
--output text
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS has recently announced support for instance tags in Instance Metadata Service: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/01/instance-tags-amazon-ec2-instance-metadata-service/

If you have have the [tag metadata option enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#work-with-tags-in-IMDS:%7E:text=To%20allow%20access%20to%20tags%20in%20instance%20metadata%20at%20launch%20using%20the%20AWS%20CLI) for an instance, you can simply do

```bash
$ TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 900"`
$ curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance
```

Comment: A nice updated answer :) Worth mention that metadata option for tags is Disabled by default

Answer (score 0):

Install AWS CLI:

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
sudo apt-get install unzip
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Get the tags for the current instance:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=`ec2metadata --instance-id`"
```

Outputs:

```
{
    "Tags": [
        {
            "ResourceType": "instance", 
            "ResourceId": "i-6a7e559d", 
            "Value": "Webserver", 
            "Key": "Name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Use a bit of perl to extract the tags:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters \
"Name=resource-id,Values=`ec2metadata --instance-id`" | \
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /\"Value\": \"(.*?)\"/'
```

Returns:

```
Webserver
```

Comment: `ec2metadata` isn't in aws-cli, but it can be replaced with `curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`. also, `jq` can parse the json easier, or a different output format is even easier.

Comment: This works, however I need to add following: `sudo apt-get -y install python` and `export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-1`

Comment: This will not work...
1. ec2metadata is incorrect command.

2. ec2-metadata --instance-id will return `instance-id: i-07f59f3564618f148`

Answer (score 0):

For those crazy enough to use Fish shell on EC2, here's a handy snippet for your /home/ec2-user/.config/fish/config.fish. The hostdata command now will list all your tags as well as the public IP and hostname.

```
set -x INSTANCE_ID (wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
set -x REGION (wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/.$//')

function hostdata
    aws ec2 describe-tags --region $REGION --filter "Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID" --output=text | sed -r 's/TAGS\t(.*)\t.*\t.*\t(.*)/\1="\2"/'
    ec2-metadata | grep public-hostname
    ec2-metadata | grep public-ipv4
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the above answers if you have awsPowerShell tools installed you can get instance-id with

```
Get-EC2InstanceMetadata -Category  InstanceId
```