# How to get the tags from an Amazon AWS EC2 instance with java library

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

I have been using [Typica](http://code.google.com/p/typica/) as my java library of choice for interfacing with my EC2 and EBS instances.  AWS recently added tags to their [API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?Using_Tags.html), but it seems that Typica has not updated to support the tags ability inside their [ImageDescription](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/code/typica/typica/1.7.2/typica-1.7.2-javadoc.jar!/com/xerox/amazonws/ec2/ImageDescription.html) object.

Has anyone used a 3rd party library in java for interfacing with the tags API in EC2?  Is there any alternatives (other than rolling it myself) that I'm missing?

Comment: There was another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883315/query-ec2-tags-from-within-instance) on SO that pointed out the new tag API, but didn't mention anything about updated library options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the latest features you'd better use [Amazon AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/), their original library.

After you get used to, is not that bad, and you can also wrap it with your classes to make it behave the way you like.

Comment: I looked at the SDK on [github](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-toolkit-for-eclipse) but it seemed to much more sparse than typica without the tag features.  It seemed to have a bunch of eclipse plugin code, but not as much for actually managing instances.

Comment: It looks like there is a post on the forums that gives more info here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=207378&#207378

Comment: It's easier to look at the [JavaDoc](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) rather than directly at the sourcecode. Did you try already to write some code?

Comment: Ya, I was looking at the JavaDoc.  The tags functionality is there.  That is the forum post I posted.  Everything looks good now that I'm using the AWS SDK rather than typica.