# shell script to set amazon ec2 hostname from tags

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami, ec2-api-tools

I am trying to set amazon EC2 hostname from the tag "Name"

And found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7122649/957423) to extract tags from instance data.

```
ec2-describe-tags \
  --filter "resource-type=instance" \
  --filter "resource-id=$(ec2-metadata -i | cut -d ' ' -f2)" \
  --filter "key=Name" | cut -f5
```

the result is:

```
+------------+--------------+------+--------+
| resourceId | resourceType | key  | value  |
+------------+--------------+------+--------+
| i-1xxxxxxx | instance     | Name | dev200 |
+------------+--------------+------+--------+
```

I can see that I am almost there, but how do I get the value(dev200) from the result above?  Then I can use it in:

```
echo $HOSTNAME > /etc/hostname
```

p.s. I have BASH on the instance, but I am completely lost in the [bash document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). can someone point me to the correct paragraph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some error and trial, got the script working:

```
#!/bin/bash
hostname=`ec2-describe-tags --filter "resource-type=instance" \
  --filter "resource-id=$(ec2-metadata -i | cut -d ' ' -f2)" \
  --filter "key=Name" | grep Name`

IFS="|" read -ra NAME <<< "$hostname"
hostname=${NAME[4]}
echo $hostname
```

Used IFS to get the string parsed into arrays, and luckily I know the 4th element is always the hostname.

EDIT (20-DEC-2012): In the short time since this was posted, several of the relevant ec2 command line tools have been modified, and flags changed or deprecated (e.g., the -i flag from above no longer seems to work on the current version of ec2metadata).  Bearing that in mind, here is the command line script I used to get the current machine's "Name" tag (can't speak to the rest of the script):

```
ec2-describe-tags --filter "resource-type=instance" --filter "resource-id=$(ec2metadata --instance-id)" | awk '{print $5}'
```

On Debian/Ubuntu, you need to `apt-get install cloud-utils ec2-api-tools` to get these working (the later is only on Ubuntu Multiverse).

Comment: Another example filtering by the `hostname` tag key:

`ec2-describe-tags --filter "resource-type=instance" --filter "key=hostname" --filter "resource-id=$(ec2metadata --instance-id)" | awk '{print $5}'`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use curl, since it is usually installed.

assigned_host_name=$(curl 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/assigned_host_name')
assigned_domain_name=$(curl 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/assigned_domain_name')

Then just check that the values assigned don't contain a 404 HTML message like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> <head> <title>404 - Not Found</title> </head> <body> <h1>404 - Not Found</h1> </body> </html>
```

Thenn do whatever magic you want to assign hostname. I'll edit this later today to add how I did that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get name tag is below.

```
hostname=$(aws ec2 describe-tags \
    --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)" \
    --query 'Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value' \
    --output text)
```

And then you can set the hostname using `hostnamectl`.

```
hostnamectl set-hostname "$hostname"
```