# Heroku style `heroku config:add VAR=val` in Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any way to set config/environment variables in EC2 for sensitive information, much like one would set `S3_KEY` or `S3_SECRET` in Heroku.

As documented on Heroku's site: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

```
$ heroku config:add GITHUB_USERNAME=joesmith
Adding config vars and restarting myapp... done, v12
GITHUB_USERNAME: joesmith

$ heroku config
GITHUB_USERNAME: joesmith
OTHER_VAR:       production

$ heroku config:get GITHUB_USERNAME
joesmith

$ heroku config:remove GITHUB_USERNAME
Unsetting GITHUB_USERNAME and restarting myapp... done, v13
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you're using Elastic Beanstalk to configure your EC2 instances. Here's the marketing: http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/10/02/introducing-aws-elastic-beanstalk-configuration-files/

I would guess that [OpWorks](https://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/) also does this, but I haven't tested.

Comment: I think we may be looking for something closer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7122649/671432