# How to get the instance Name from the instance in AWS?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set up a means to register an instance in route53 automatically when the instance is created, using salt and [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130906075018/http://cantina.co/2012/01/25/automated-dns-for-aws-instances-using-route-53/).

The article uses `ec2-metadata` to get the instance-id and and the hostname. I'm wondering if there is a way, using bash within the instance, to get the instance Name instead. `ec2-metadata` only seems to show the instance-id. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please accept the correct answer so that all people can get the right thing fastly. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

First, you need to get the `instance-id`.

```
AWS_INSTANCE_ID=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
```

Than you can get the `ec2 instance name` using below command.

```
EC2_NAME=$(aws ec2 describe-tags --region $REGION --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$AWS_INSTANCE_ID" "Name=key,Values=Name" --output text | cut -f5)
```

Please ensure that you have [AWS Cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux-al2017.html) Installed.

Comment: I get `'AWSHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute 'ssl_context'` Permissions with IAM?

Comment: I am not sure about this error. But may be this can help you. 
https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1258

Comment: @numb3rs1x If my answer seems ok to you, Please accept it as a correct answer so that others can get relevant answer more faster.

Comment: just FYI, "cat /var/lib/cloud/data/instance-id" will print the instance ID from within the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 23):

First and foremost, the [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) *Instance Metadata Service* also provides quite some other *Names* besides the `instance-id`, if these might be what you are looking for - see [Instance Metadata Categories](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html#instancedata-data-categories):

- `hostname` - *The private hostname of the instance. In cases where multiple network interfaces are present, this refers to the eth0 device (the device for which the device number is 0).*
- `local-hostname` - *The private DNS hostname of the instance. In cases where multiple network interfaces are present, this refers to the eth0 device (the device for which the device number is 0).*
- `public-hostname` - *The instance's public DNS. If the instance is in a VPC, this category is only returned if the enableDnsHostnames attribute is set to true.*

If you are looking for the *Name* as exposed in the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) though, you would indeed need to resort to using one of the [Tools for Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/tools/) to retrieve it - that *Name* is in fact just a regular tag with the key *Name* (see [Tagging Your Amazon EC2 Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html)), which happens to be used across most AWS services for the obvious purpose.

Here's how to get it with the [AWS Command Line Interface](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) for example (skipping region and credentials):

```
aws ec2 describe-tags \
--filters Name=resource-id,Values=i-abcd1234 Name=key,Values=Name \
--query Tags[].Value --output text
```

- For more advanced CLI JSON output processing than what's possible with the built in `--query` option, you could resort to [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (*a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor*).
- [Overthink's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7122649/45773) provides an example based on the now legacy [Amazon EC2 API Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-EC2/351) (please note the comments, which correctly point out that you'd nowadays deal with credentials differently, see [Tell the CLI Tools Who You Are](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SettingUp_CommandLine.html#set_aws_credentials_linux) and [IAM Roles for EC2 instances](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/06/iam-roles-for-ec2-instances-simplified-secure-access-to-aws-service-apis-from-ec2.html) for details).

Comment: You can also use the --query command line parameter along with --output to directly output just the instance name, e.g.:  `aws ec2 describe-tags --filters Name=resource-id,Values=i-abcd1234 Name=key,Values=Name --query Tags[].Value --output text`

Comment: @CarlosP - I've updated the answer with the indeed easier approach you propose (the `--query` option hadn't been available in the AWS CLI from the get go), thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: For those who get missing region error: add `--region us-east-1` to above command. @SteffenOpel Thank you for the Answer. Could you please add this region part in your answer for reachability. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what it would look like with bash, but you could use an SDK from the instance itself if you can get the instance id. You would query the ec2 recourse and pass in the ec2 instance id. Using the ruby sdk it would look like:

```
i = ec2.instances["i-12345678"]
puts i.dns_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to show which metadata is available

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"` \
&& curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

You can chain any one of the below file/folders to display the required info

```
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
events/
hostname
iam/
identity-credentials/
instance-action
instance-id
instance-life-cycle
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
metrics/
network/
placement/
profile
public-keys/
reservation-id
```

For eg. `instance-type` can be chained this to the above command as follows:

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"` \
&& curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type
```

[Reference from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html)

Comment: The question is - "How to get **instance name**"

Answer (score 0):

**ec2metadata** tool is useful to get information about the EC2 server.

You can use the following;

`ec2metadata --instance-id`

**in bash;**

`INSTANCE_ID=$(ec2metadata --instance-id)`

You can also access other useful information like the following;

```
--ami-id
--ami-launch-index
--ami-manifest-path
--ancestor-ami-ids
--availability-zone
--block-device-mapping
--instance-action
--instance-id
--instance-type
--local-hostname
--local-ipv4
--kernel-id
--mac
--profile
--product-codes
--public-hostname
--public-ipv4
--public-keys
--ramdisk-id
--reserveration-id
--security-groups
```

Comment: You are not answering his question. The poster already stated that ec2metadata does not provide the name of the instance

Answer (score -1):

Found that describe-tags not working in my config, failed with 'UnauthorizedOperation' error. Got this working with describe-instances:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-id,Values=$(wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --query Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[].Value --output text
```

Command using region and access keys from current user's aws config file's [default] section: ~/.aws/config . If need to use another user's region/keys (can be found at AWS console's IAM dashboard), you can add them to another section in that file, for example [user2] and use in command like this:

```
aws --profile user2 ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-id,Values=$(wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --query Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[].Value --output text
```