# How to dynamically switch databases based on environment when using AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-dynamodb

We are considering simplifying our stack by moving our manually created autoscaled cluster into Elastic Beanstalk. We use DynamoDB for our backend DB and I was wondering what the suggested way of switching between tables for test vs. production environment when deploying both from the same git commit. Is there an easy way to read the environment name, or is there already built in mechanisms for this?

Comment: You may consider reading tags (that you can associate with your instance). The tags may have "Prod"/"Stg" etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883315/query-ec2-tags-from-within-instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk enables you to specify environment variables per env. You start by creating two envs - test & production. Then you set specific variables to each using the `eb setenv` command or the web console.
Here's how I do it:
`eb setenv RDS_DB_NAME=dragon RDS_HOSTNAME=dragon-db.h6jhj1munhy2.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com RDS_PASSWORD=dragonpass RDS_PORT=5432 RDS_USERNAME=dragon`

Now, to switch between production and test you simply change the `RDS_HOSTNAME` env variable.