# Mesos Attributes: Source from EC2 Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I'm interested in having my mesos-slave instances inherit attributes from the EC2 tags that the slave is running on. After some searching, I don't think such a setup exists. I would like to write one and contribute it back to the community.

Our slaves are running Ubuntu and we're using the mesos packages from the mesosphere repo. This creates a beautiful [mesos-init-wrapper](https://github.com/deric/mesos-deb-packaging/blob/master/mesos-init-wrapper) that allows mesos configuration (command line arguments) to be represented as files in `/etc/mesos-slave/` or `/etc/mesos/`. I want to write a script which will:

1. Use the ec2 API to get the instance tags ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7122649/379482))
2. Generate corresponding files in `[/etc/mesos/attributes/][3]`
3. Run this script at an early run-level

Mesos community folks: is this the right way to go? Is it reasonable to build an implementation that is tied to `mesos-init-wrapper`?

Thanks!

Advait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mesos-aws-tags` is now available here: https://github.com/goguardian/mesos-aws-tags

Comment: Sounds great. Thanks for the contribution!