# How to create an aws instance using an instance template in the aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface

How do I create an instance with a chosen name from an instance template on aws.

Previously when I was on google cloud, first I created an instance template for example it was called `node-template`.

To create servers, I would use the following command in the gcloud cli,

```
gcloud instances create node-1 --source-instance-template=node-template
gcloud instances create node-2 --source-instance-template=node-template
gcloud instances create node-3 --source-instance-template=node-template
....
```

Is something similar possible with aws?

I basically need to create multiple instances with similar specs and be able to start them, SSH into them and stop them everyday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS CLI command `aws ec2 run-instances` can be used to launch Amazon EC2 instances. See: [run-instances — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html)

The command allows all parameters to be specified in JSON, and this can come from disk:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --cli-input-json file://my-parameters.json
```

See: [Loading AWS CLI parameters from a file - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html)

Alternatively, you might want to [Launch an instance from a launch template - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-templates.html), which is a pre-defined definition of an Amazon EC2 instance that is stored in your AWS Account. You can then reference this launch template when launch an instance:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --launch-template LaunchTemplateName=MY-LAUNCH-TEMPLATE
```

Names of instances can be assigned by specifying a `Name` tag:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=MY-INSTANCE-NAME}]' --launch-template LaunchTemplateName=my-launch-template
```

Comment: And I can set the host name as well? Because I need the host names to follow that format node-1 node-2 etc

Comment: I have a shell script that runs based on the host name and number

Comment: You can run a script via [Run commands on your Windows instance at launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html) and [Run commands on your Linux instance at launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

Comment: can the name variable be accessed within the vm ?

Comment: No. The 'Name' is stored as a tag on the EC2 instance. You would need to call `DescribeTags()` on AWS to obtain the name. This is, of course, different to the name that the operating system itself applies to the computer. See: [Query EC2 tags from within instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7122649/174777)